# split array regex (a but not ab, without losing char after a)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following

```
var example = "caty not caby";
example.split(/a[^b]/);
```

which returns

```
[ "c", "y not caby" ]
```

but I'm trying to get

```
["c","ty not caby"]
```

How could I split the string at every 'a' but not every 'ab' without losing the char after the 'a' (which in the example above is 't')?

Comment: `/a(?!b)/` (negative lookahead)

Comment: Or `s.match(/(?:ab|[^a])+/g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have mentioned negative lookahead but I'll try to explain *why* you need to use it.

Your regex `a[^b]` matches **a** *and* the next character, as long as it's not **b**, so it's always going to be two. In your example string, that is "c**at**y not caby" because **at** matches both of those.

Lookahead patterns, however are called *zero width* because they do a check but are not considered part of the match, so `a(?!b)` will match exactly one character, even though the pattern used both **a** and **b**.

```
caty not caby
 ^^       ^
 ||       checked and rejected
 ||
 |checked but not considered part of the match
 character matched because the lookahead test passed
```

So, this is why this works.

```js
var example = "caty not caby";
var split = example.split(/a(?!b)/)
console.log(split);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead and exclude the sequence for splitting.

```js
var example = "caty not caby";
console.log(example.split(/a(?!b)/));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [negated lookahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead):

```
/a(?!b)/
```

```js
var example = "caty not caby";
console.log(example.split(/a(?!b)/));
```